# AngularJS is does not update template

Tags: angularjs

I have two templates, `_frontpage.html` and `_movieOverview.html`. I inject both of the templates on my `application.html.haml`, like so:

```
%div{"ui-view" => ""}
%div{"ng-controller" => "searchCtrl", "ng-include" => "'assets/angular-app/templates/_movieOverview.html.haml'", :id => "container_frontpage"}
```

I've used router-ui to make a home state in which the `_frontpage.html` is injected with my searchCtrl.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'searchCtrl',
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_frontpage.html',
  })
```

In my `_frontpage.html` template I have a search field. Users can search a movie title and a list of posters is created. Then they can click on the poster to add that movie to the database. The `_movieOverview.html` renders all the results.

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'release_date' | filter:{user_id: user_id} "}
```

My problem is that when a user adds a new movie to the database the `_movieOverview.html` template does not get updated. Only when I refresh the page do I see the new movie added.

But when I inject the `_movieOverview.html` template inside the `_frontpage.html` template like so,

```
%div{"ng-include" => "'assets/angular-app/templates/_movieOverview.html.haml'", :id => "container_frontpage"}
```

Then when I add a movie to the database the template gets updated with the new movie. But now I have a template inside a template which I don't want.

So my question is, how do I update a template (show new movie) with an action from a different template (do a search action and add a movie to the database).

Some code from my `searchCtrl.js`

The code for the search action,

```
  $scope.search = function() {

    if($('#search_input').val()) {
      // Input field has value

      var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
      var service = '/search/movie';
      var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
      var search = $scope.searchquery
      var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
      var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

      $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          if (status == 200) {
            $scope.movieList = data.results;
            console.log($scope.movieList)
          } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          }

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        });

    } else {
      // do nothing
    }
  }
```

When a user adds a movie this function fires,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

    'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
    // Search for release dates using the ID.
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
    var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
    var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
    var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

    $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {

          $scope.movieListID = data;
          console.log($scope.movieListID);

          var releaseNL;

          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
            var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
            if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
                releaseNL = release;
            }
          }

          if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
            // With release date

            Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);

          } else {
            Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);
          };

        } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        }
      })
```

Important here is the `.then(init);` which refers to this,

```
  var init = function(){

    movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
      $scope.movies = response.data;
    });

  }
  init();
```

Comment: Where is the controller code for updating the model, scope and database?

Comment: Are you updating the `$scope.movies` property with the updated list?

Comment: @MattWay I've added code from my searchcontroller which refers to the search action, the add action and the update.

Comment: You probably need a $scope.$apply() around the code that is setting you values on the $scope. This is because you are mixing up jQuery and Angular and you are now outside the digest loop of Angular.

Comment: @BasSlagter I'm not sure if I understant what you mean with "around the code that is setting your value on the $scope". If I add an apply to my `var init` I get an error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`. I also get the same error when I use it around the `createMovie.create` function.